# Postback And UpdatePanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, updatepanel

I recently learned you can do a postback from javascript using

```
__doPostBack('#<%=LinkButton.UniqueID%>', '')
```

This method worked well for me, even with updatepanels but now I added another LinkButton and tried to do a postback using the method above. It works but the page refreshes.

I added this LinkButton to an updatepanel and set a trigger. When I normally click on the LinkButton , it doesn't refresh, but when I try the java postback, it does.

---

*Got it to work if I write ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$LinkButton

But this way isnt good for me because I can't change it everytime I move the control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice here that you have add the # symbol. This used on jQuery, not here, just remove it and its work.

```
__doPostBack('<%=LinkButton.UniqueID%>', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the ClientIDMode attribute on your link button, set it to 'static'.

Should do the trick for you :-)